# Any Ubuntu/torrent friendly VPN Provider recommendations?

Tags: vpn, bittorrent

I am dropping the service (VPNUK) due to poor customer support, so does anybody have any good Ubuntu/torrent friendly VPN Provider recommendations?

Comment: This question is more suited as a list or discussion.  As such it doesn't fit well with the QA format.  Try our friends over at UbuntuForums.

Comment: This looks off-topic. You just need someone who is torrent-friendly and supports PPTP(Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using AirVPN - https://airvpn.org/ - for some months now and haven't had any problems.

You should probably also take a look at this for other suggestions:

https://torrentfreak.com/which-vpn-providers-really-take-anonymity-seriously-111007/